# client can't send data to server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to build a connection from browser to server side which written in node.js

when the client side connect to the server , the server side will send a message to client and the server will receive message when the client click the send button.

but the client side can receive the message from server side , but server side can't receive message from client side

client side code

```
<center>
    <input id="send" type="submit" value="send">
    <p id="recv"></p>
</center>

<script src="library/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:7000");
    var send = document.getElementById("send");
    var recv = document.getElementById("recv");

    send.addEventListener("click",function () {
        socket.emit("message","message_from_client");
    });

    socket.on("message",function (data) {
        recv.innerHTML = data;
    });
</script>
```

server side client

```
var socket = require("socket.io").listen(7000);

socket.on("connect",function () {
    console.log("connect");
    socket.emit("message","message_from_server");
});

socket.on("message",function (data) {
    console.log(data);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code on server side? I seen it work.

```
var socket = require("socket.io").listen(7000);

socket.on("connect", function(client) {
    console.log("connect");
    client.emit("message", "message_from_server");

    client.on("message", function(data) {
        console.log(data);

    });
});
```

You can check sample code and document on this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io)

Comment: This is the right idea and does illustrate one of the problems in the OP's code.  If this isn't working, then there is something else wrong because this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `io.sockets.emit('event', message)` on the client. This will send the message to all connected sockets, including the server.